# Access IP cams from WAN with VPN active on router

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to access my IP cams from WAN whilst OpenVPN client (PIA) is active on my router. The camera streams are fed by the NAS surveillance station, through the QNAP VMobile app for iPhone.

My setup is as follows:

-ASUS RT-AC87U standard firmware with PIA as OpenVPN client installed on the router.

-QNAP NAS with 2 Foscam C1 V2 IP cams.

-Port forward setup for incoming requests for port 443 (SSL port of the NAS) to LAN static IP of the NAS. This is the only port forward on my router.

-UPnP is disabled on the router.

-I am accessing the camera streams using the QNAP VMobile app (but I am open to suggestions for other tools to use).

This all works fine, if PIA is not enabled. But as soon as I enable the PIA VPN on the router, I can't access my IP cams anymore. Just to be clear, I am accessing the IP cams through the NAS, not through the camera itself.

Can't figure out why this is happening, and how to solve it. The IP address given to my router by PIA is correctly reflected in the QNAP remote access service (myQNAPcloud) but somehow the login method through myQNAPcloud does not work anymore if PIA is switched on.

I've contacted both QNAP and PIA but they are pointing to each-other.

Any suggestion are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You'd be better asking this on the networking stack exchange. You'd need to know IP addresses of NAS, VPN router, and routing tables. My guess is you VPN does not forward packets to NAS therefore you need to add NAS subnet to the routable networks on OpenVPN router.

Comment: Sorry, no. Networkengineering mod here. Home networking questions and questions about consumer grade equipment are explicitly off topic there. [su] would be the place to go.

Comment: Why have you got port forward open when using the open vpn server within the router? You don’t need to do that the Asus router handles opening the OpenVPN ports, and you therefore don’t need the port to the QNAP box directly mapped

Comment: Also make sure any whitelisting on the QNAP has the gateway ip of the OpenVPN as well. Might be best to white list the OpenVPN is range to the QNAP. I’ve got this exact setup working, same router as well and it works fine. I don’t use the QNAPcloud things though. I just access the QNAP box directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will post the same question again on Super User. However just wanted to jump in on ISMSDEV's comments: 1) in the router, I am not using OpenVPN server, but OpenVPN client. Is that comment on handling the port mapping automatically still valid in that case? So I just remove the port forward then? Any additional config in the router? 2) for whitelisting, do you mean adding the default gateway IP of the router in my QNAP?

Comment: 3) you mention you access the QNAP directly, but from which app / tool? If you are using the VMobile app, which login method do you use? If you're not using VMobile app, which app/tool are you using? I need to view the videostreams on my iPhone.

Comment: please do not cross-post - let us migrate next time